# New to A-Frame and coding, trying to load a .gtlf model but not working

Tags: aframe

New to A-frame and coding, trying to display a 3d scanned object on a marker. I upload a .gtlf to my asset folder and it's not loading when viewing the Hiro marker on my Galaxy s9+

I've added (scale="0.2 0.2 0.2") but that doesn't work.

Used http://github.khronos.org/glTF-Validator/ to make sure my .gtlf is valid and it is.

Tried both .gtlf and .glb to see if that was the issue but both doesn't load.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Pizza test hoho</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Let's hope this work!">
    <link id="favicon" rel="icon" href="https://glitch.com/edit/favicon-app.ico" type="image/x-icon">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.6.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
    <!--     Save commit version of aframe-arjs before the rewrite around August 8, 2017 -->
    <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/jeromeetienne/AR.js/ec578832d908e3b33bb1da9c649543e151395c21/aframe/build/aframe-ar.min.js"></script>
    <script>THREEx.ArToolkitContext.baseURL = 'https://rawgit.com/jeromeetienne/ar.js/master/three.js/'</script>
    <script src="./js/index.js"></script>
    <style>
      .note {
        position: absolute;
                     top: 1%;
                     left: 1%;
                     color: black;
                     text-shadow:
                     -1px -1px 0 #BBB,
                     1px -1px 0 #BBB,
                     -1px 1px 0 #BBB,
                     1px 1px 0 #BBB;
      }
      a-scene {
        pointer-events: none;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="note" style="position: absolute;
                     top: 1%;
                     left: 1%;
                     color: black;
                     text-shadow:
                     -1px -1px 0 #BBB,
                     1px -1px 0 #BBB,
                     -1px 1px 0 #BBB,
                     1px 1px 0 #BBB;">
      You'll need to have <a href="https://jeromeetienne.github.io/AR.js/data/images/HIRO.jpg">this image</a> printed or just displaying on your phone!
    </div>
    <a-scene artoolkit="sourceType: webcam;" embedded="embedded">

        <a-marker-camera preset="hiro">

            <a-entity gltf-model="https://cdn.glitch.com/168b6551-08b1-4c03-b4ae-f1f4ca3e8031%2FPizza.glb?1557619896347" scale="0.2 0.2 0.2"></a-entity>

        </a-marker-camera>
    </a-scene>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Couple of issues here:

1) Framework versions

- aframe 0.6.0 i believe used gtlf 1.0. Switch to 0.9.2.
  From the [docs](https://aframe.io/docs/0.9.0/introduction/): `https://aframe.io/releases/0.9.1/aframe.min.js`
- ar.js as well in the docs has a different link (this may be less relevant)
  [Docs](https://github.com/jeromeetienne/AR.js/blob/master/README.md): `https://cdn.rawgit.com/jeromeetienne/AR.js/1.6.2/aframe/build/aframe-ar.js`

2) The model (at least the .glb file) is freakin 63 megabytes. Considering you make it for a phone, it takes a couple seconds on a wifi, but I wouldn't expect anyone to load a file this big as a website asset.

This may be my opinion, but the more complex the model is, it becomes less likely to behave properly on a phone.

At [this glitch](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/honey-parrotfish?path=index.html:28:29), you can check it out working - tried with my PC, and on andoid firefox.

Comment: The glitch you link doesn't seem to work for me, unless my internet is bad at the moment. How long did it take for the model to load up?